# File is not getting downloaded using selenium chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to download some csv files using selenium webdriver from dynamic loaded website where i need to click buttons to get my file downloaded. However when i run my python script in my local machine all files will get downloaded but same script wont download files in AWS Linux server machine. It neither gives me an error during the downloads.

arguments I added for driver

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = GoogleChrome_Path
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory": SomeFolder,
                                          "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                                          "download.directory_upgrade": True,
                                          "safebrowsing.enabled": True
                                          })
```

And right after this i will perform some click operations to download the file and as i have stated above when it executes in the Linux server machine the files wont get downloaded and also the script does not throw any error

How do i know that file wont get downloaded?
well, I check the files in save path folder using

```
os.listdir(SomeFolder)
```

Is there any way that I can find out what is causing this issue

Element tag that I am trying to click

```
<a title="CSV (comma delimited)" alt="CSV (comma delimited)" onclick="$find('ctl_ReportViewer').exportReport('CSV');" href="javascript:void(0)" style="color: rgb(51, 102, 204); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px 8px 3px 32px; display: block; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none;">CSV (comma delimited)</a>
```

Source URL
https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12

select random drop down values and click **display report** and it takes some seconds to load the report. after completely loaded we can see blue color button(Export drop down menu) click that button and export to csv

I am just having problem while clicking export as a csv.

[image]

Comment: How did you perform the click ? Was there enough delay ?

Comment: I use driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", CSV) to download the files. and yes the files are relatively small and i use sleep method time.sleep(100) . this still doesnt work. @cruisepandey

Comment: I would recommend to use WebDriverWait, something like `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xpath of download button"))).click()` and see if that helps

Comment: that will require these imports as well `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

Comment: @cruisepandey Thanks. will check this one.

Comment: Sure let me know how it goes.

Comment: @cruisepandey sorry, Looks like it is not working. btw I have edited my question and added element tag. I see something like onclick in tag , may be some other way to handle this onlick element!

Comment: I have given a solution below, basically 3 ways to perform a click. try each of them and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below `CSS_SELECTOR` :

```
a[title^='CSV (comma delimited)'][onclick*='CSV']
```

Using **Explicit waits :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title^='CSV (comma delimited)'][onclick*='CSV']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Directly use driver.find_element**

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title^='CSV (comma delimited)'][onclick*='CSV']").click()
```

If these 2 do not work, try JS :-

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title^='CSV (comma delimited)'][onclick*='CSV']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Comment: Thanks. This trows me an error - selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

Comment: All 3 of them ?

Comment: Yea. I added URL in my question . if you want to check. I am sorry I don't know much about selenium chrome driver.

Comment: Sure I will, it may take couple of hours.

Comment: Server Error in '/flumart' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file

Comment: I could not navigate till desire page, Could you tell me the navigation steps that I have to take  ?

Comment: Hi, is the website not loading or you are unable to locate download button?

Comment: Website is loading but when I click on display report, I am getting the above mentioned exception

Comment: I am not sure. may be the url you are using is : https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default  

please use this one : https://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12

Comment: Negative, Is this your company production URL ?

Comment: No its not. Its a public website

Comment: seems like some problem. anyways thanks for all the help, i will accept this answer since you put lot of effort. Thanks once again